# exp x in Haskell and type signature

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I defined the custom exponentiation `exp'` function in GHCi as:

```
let exp' x = sum $ take 100 [(x**k) / factorial k | k <- [0..]]
```

which yields the following type signature:

```
#> :t exp'
exp' :: (Enum a, Floating a) => a -> a
```

However, I would have expected it to match that of the `exp` function, i.e.

```
#> :t exp
exp :: Floating a => a -> a
```

Can anybody explain the `Enum a => a` type constraint of my `exp'` function? Why isn't it just `Floating a => a`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It originates from the `k <- [0..]` - that desugars to use the `Enum` class.

It then propagates into the final type signature because you're using `(**)` for exponentiation which expects its arguments to be the same type:

```
(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
```

One option is to use `(^)` for exponentiation instead:

```
(^) :: (Integral b, Num a) => a -> b -> a
```

You'll also need to convert `factorial k` to the right type, with something like `fromIntegral`:

```
exp' x = sum $ take 100 [(x^k) / fromIntegral (factorial k) | k <- [0..]]
```

It's possibly a better fit for this case because your exponents will be integers, although it may be a bit less efficient as it uses repeated multiplication (logarithmic in the exponent) rather than constant-time floating point operations.

Alternatively (as suggested in a comment), to stick with `(**)`, use `fromIntegral` to move from an enumeration over `Int` to the actual type you are working with:

```
let exp' x = sum $ take 100 [(x**fromIntegral k) / fromIntegral (factorial k)
                                                        | k <- [0..]]
```

Comment: Another option is `[(x**k)/factorial k | k <- map fromIntegral [0..]]`

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, that makes perfect sense. I tried replacing `(**)` with `(^)` but GHCi complains that _The type variable `a0` is ambiguous_. So I added the function signature `exp' :: (Enum a, Floating a) => a -> a` explicitly but that won't compile now, saying: _Could not deduce (Integral a) arising from a use of `^`_

Comment: Oh yes - give `[0..]` a type signature (e.g. `[0..] :: [Int]`). Otherwise GHC doesn't know what integral type to pick for the exponent .

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam The problem isn't that `GHC` doesn't know to pick `Int`.  In fact if `Integer` fit then it would default to that with no type annotation. The problem is probably that `k` is also used in `/ factorial k`, and that somehow gives `k`'s type a constraint which `Int` and `Integer` *cannot* fulfil. (My guess is on `Fractional`.)  Adding another `fromIntegral` to that should fix it.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Sorry but your suggested `exp'` in your edit doesn't even compile in GHCi.

Comment: Can you give the definition of factorial?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam: Just `let factorial n = toInteger $ product [1..n]`.

Comment: Try the updated versions - needed another `fromIntegral` as Ørjan suggested

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Much obliged!

Answer (score 1):

`[0..]` is converted into

```
enumFrom 0
```

and `enumFrom` has type `Enum a => a -> [a]` so the compiler infers that `k` must be an enum type.